# how to use PHP json_decode() function for array of JSON objects

Tags: php, html, json

I have an array of PHP objects. These objects are json_encoded. Then I display a table in html using attributes in one object as one row in the table. For that I json_decode the objects one by one using a for loop and display the table. But after json_decoding I dont get the original object back. I cant access variables of it.

```
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x <= sizeof($objArray); $x++) {
    $obj = $objArray[$x];
    $obj = json_decode($obj);
?>
    <tr id="<?php echo $x ?>">
        <th id="obj-<?php echo $x ?>"><?php echo $obj->getName() ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $obj->getSchool() ?></td>
        <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
<?php }
?>
```

The code that I use in the server side to return the objects is as follows

```
$objs = //array of php objects 
$objArray =array();

foreach($objs as $values){
    array_push($objArray,json_encode($values));
}
return json_encode($objArray);
```

Comment: The json_decoded objects will be pure data objects and not harbor any getMethods.

Comment: what does pure data objects means? The object that I loop through in the for loop belongs to a particular object type I declared which have those get methods implemented. Cant I access those methods

Comment: No. They're stdClass objects at this point. // The convoluted json_encode of each row doesn't change that.

Comment: Thank you I understood the problem. The array that I return therefore shouldn't be converted to json for me to access the methods right. So if I also wants to access this array of PHP objects inside javascript is there a method that I can use. I'm stuck  in the process of finding the a way to access this array of php objects from javascript

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `json_encode` and `json_decode` the PHP object will be translated into a pure json string and any PHP related information about this object, like `methods` will be lost.

You could use [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.serialize.php) on the server side to convert the object into a string and keeping all the relevant object information for php.

In your frontend code you could then use [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php) to convert the string back into a valid PHP object.

A small side note:
In your code example you are `json_encoding` your values twice. This can also lead to unwanted side effects.

Comment: Thank you but if if I only json_encode() the array I cant access the php objects inside the array in javascript. Is there a way for me to access the objects in javascript

Comment: By only using `json_encode / json_decode` there is no way to access the objects in your frontend.
As soon as you use `json_encode()` on your object, method information is lost.
If you need to return json in your backend, use `serialize()` and json_encode the string.